# Project almost complete, output is wrong and will not display properly, have been unable to find my error.

Tags: c#, visual-studio, output

I am almost finished with the program, but my output is wrong, and after 5 hours, I am still unable to figure out what I did wrong, and thought it may be helpful to seek a fresh set of eyes. I have a Demo program given by my instructor, so I took a screen shot to show clearly what it should look like.

[image: on the right, my program shows no output, on the left is the demo program working correctly]

My code for that chunk is this:

```
   //array add student data to the array
    if (currentStudentArrayIndex >= constArrayMaxSize)
    {
    MessageBox.Show("Array is full, cannot add any more to the array");
    }
    else
    {
    arrayNames [currentStudentArrayIndex] = studentName;
    arrayGrades [currentStudentArrayIndex] = studentGrade;
    MessageBox.Show("Student data has been entered into array index " +                                  currentStudentArrayIndex);
    textBoxName.Text = "";
    textBoxGrade.Text = "";
    }

    //array output
    currentStudentArrayIndex = currentStudentArrayIndex + 1;

    }

    //array display
    private void buttonDisp_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    string myString = "";
    string studentName = "";
    int studentGrade = 0;
     myString = "Student Data Entered So Far:\n";

    //loop through array
    for(int i = 0; i  < arrayNames.Length; i++)
    {
    myString = myString +
    "Array[" + i + "]  ==>   " +
    "Student #" + (i + 1);

    if (arrayGrades[i] == 0)
    {
    myString = myString + "     (NOT ENTERED)";
    }
    else
    {
    myString = myString +
    "     Name:" +arrayNames[i] +
    "     Grade:" + arrayGrades[i].ToString("c");

    studentName = studentName + arrayNames[i];
    studentGrade = studentGrade + arrayGrades[i];
    }
    //output
    labelDisplay.Text = myString;

    }
```

Obviously myString isn't working, but I'm unsure why, what did I do to it? Any suggestions, useful links, or guidance is much appreciated!

Comment: Have you verified that the your buttonDisp_Click() is actually getting called?  Or that arrayNames has values?  Incidentally, StringBuilder is generally a better choice for building up a string.

Comment: I didn't even think to check my button... one moment!

Comment: annd I'm an idiot. That was it! -_- thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Button buttonDisp was incorrect. Using the correct button name corrected the problem, allowing the information to display properly.